# threaded buffer: how to prevent racing between clients and have client and server working on buffer simultaneously

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, circular-buffer

I made a program that has a few threaded clients that can store information into a circular buffer; the server can read (and 'remove') the messages from the circular buffer. The problem I have is when the buffer is full; the client that is currently writing into the buffer has to release the mutex (the server than removes all data from the buffer) but when releasing the mutex the client race and the client that was already busy is not necessarily the first to continue his transmission; so his message gets mixed up. Any one know's how to solve this? Or do you have proposals for a better way of doing this. Eventually I want to make a multithreaded tcp server were the messages are stored in a buffer and than retransmitted by the server to all clients so you know what I'm gonna use it for. Also can I not lock the buffer so the server is continuously retrieving data when it wants or is this impossible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct cBuf{
    int     size;   /* maximum number of slots */
    int     start;  /* index of oldest element (last element) */
    int     end;    /* index at which to write new element (first element) */
    char    *buf;  /* buffer array */
};

struct cBuf cb;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

/* Initialize buffer*/
void buf_Init(struct cBuf *cb, int size) {
    cb->size  = size + 1; /* empty element */
    cb->start = 0;
    cb->end   = 0; 
    cb->buf = (char *)calloc(cb->size, sizeof(char)); //pointer to beginning of allocated memory
}
/* Clean up buffer*/
void buf_Free(struct cBuf *cb) {
    free(cb->buf);
}

/* Is the the buffer full? if it equals size meaning the buffer is full: end will point to zero (ex. 7%7 is 0) */ 
int buf_IsFull(struct cBuf *cb) {
    return (cb->end + 1) % cb->size == cb->start; 
}

/* Is the buffer empty? Yes if both start & end are zero (are equal) */
int cbIsEmpty(struct cBuf *cb) {
    return cb->end == cb->start; 
}

/* Write an element, overwriting oldest element if buffer is full. App can
   choose to avoid the overwrite by checking cbIsFull(). */
/* When inserting an element acces needs to be blocked (only 1 insert at a time =>mutexes 
 * When buffer is full it should return -1 so we can block the request*/
int buf_Insert(struct cBuf *cb, char *elem) {
    if (buf_IsFull(cb)){
        //buffer is full; cannot write into the buffer
        //sleep(2);
        return 0;
    } else {
        /* When writing to the buffer, the buffer has to be locked first (will block when already locked)*/
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        cb->buf[cb->end] = *elem; //we put the new character in the last free slot
        /* we move the index for the next slot one further */
        cb->end = (cb->end + 1) % cb->size; 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        return 1;
    }
}

/* Read oldest element. Ensure !cbIsEmpty() first. */
int buf_Read(struct cBuf *cb, char *out) {
    if (!cbIsEmpty(cb)){
        /* When reading from the buffer, the buffer has to be locked first (will block when already locked)*/
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        *out = cb->buf[cb->start];
        cb->start = (cb->start + 1) % cb->size; //are news oldest character is now the next one
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        return 1;
    }
    //buffer is emtpy
    return 0;
}

void * client(void *cb){
    //sleep (2);
    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\nDEBUG (Thread ID:%lu) - Entering thread\t",(unsigned long)pthread_self());
    #endif

    /* main thread does not need to wait and this way all resources are released when terminating*/
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    struct cBuf *myData;
    myData = (struct cBuf*) cb;
    int i;

    /* client will post message in the buffer */
    char input[]="Hello World!";

    //printf("I:\t");
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(input); ++ i){ 
        if (buf_Insert(myData, &input[i]) ){
            //printf("[I]%c",input[i]);
        } else {
            //the buffer is full; wait until it has been emptied + go back a step because of lost character
            i--;    
            #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\nDEBUG (Main Thread) - Full Buffer");  
            #endif
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int bufferSize = 20; /* arbitrary size */
    char out;
    pthread_t thread;
    int j;

    buf_Init(&cb, bufferSize);

    //we make 1 client for starters
    for (j = 0; j<4; j++){
        if(pthread_create (&thread,NULL, client, (void *) &cb) !=0){
            #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\nDEBUG (Main Thread) - Error while creating thread");
            #endif
        } else {
            #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\nDEBUG (Main Thread) - Thread created");
            #endif
        }
    }

    while (1){
        /* Server will read (and thus remove) the message */
        if (cbIsEmpty(&cb)){
            //sleep(2);
            #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\nDEBUG (Main Thread) - Buffer is empty");
            #endif
        } else {
            printf("\tO:\t");
            while (buf_Read(&cb,&out)){
                printf("%c", out);
            }
            #ifdef DEBUG        
            if (buf_Read(&cb, &out) == 0){
                printf("\nDEBUG (Main Thread) - Finished reading");
            }
            #endif
            printf("\n");   
        }
    }

    //empty the buffer; free the allocated memory
    buf_Free(&cb);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a typical use case for a `pthread_cond_t` that you'd use in addtition to the `pthread_mutex_t` to signal (and check) threads selectively.

Comment: i don't see how? i mean it would be nice to signal the client when the server has read all the values in the full buffer but how can the server change the buffer while it is mutexed by the client?

Comment: @Thomas Verbeke The client doesn't hold the mutex. If you use a pthread_cond_t, waiting/waking up also releases/aquires the mutex, and is done in a safe and atomic way.

Comment: so are you saying that: I signal the server that the buffer is full; this releases the mutex but the server will 100% be the first one to lock the mutex again so he can start removing values from the buffer; when the server is ready he signals the client that was putting values inside the buffer to continue and that buffer will again be the first one to lock the buffer

Comment: No, you'd need 2 cond variables one that will halt the producer when the buffer is full and resume it when it is not full, and one for halting the consumer when the buffer is empty and resume the consumer when it is non-empty.

Comment: But why use two cond variables? If i use one than the server can continue doing other things at the same time, no? Also can the producer and consumer operate simultaneously?

Comment: Stuff only sleep IFF: the queue is full (in which case the producer needs to stop adding stuff to the queue). Or IFF the queue is empty (then the consumer needs to wait for somone to add something to the queue). In other cases, they run more or less concurrently. There's tons and tons of examples of consumer/producer queues like this around